# React flushSync() isn't working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am clear that the following is not a good practice. However, I would like to know why this snippet is not working after I click on the button if I'm using `flushSync()`.
When I say that it is not working, I'm referring to the fact that the alert is showing "Hello, !" and during subsequent clicks, it shows the previous state instead of the current one.

```
export default function FeedbackForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  function handleClick() {
    flushSync(() => {
      setName(prompt('What is your name?'))
    })

    alert(`Hello, ${name}!`);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Greet
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading here and there, I arrived at the following conclusion:

React forces the update of the DOM using `flushSync()`, but this doesn't mean it also updates the state variable (`name`) immediately because, as we know, React updates the state asynchronously.

This approach would be more suitable **if you want to obtain some updated information from the DOM, but you need to set a state first.**

Anyways, the documentation advises against using this method unless it is absolutely necessary.